# Do you change the mean / standard deviation when calculating the unbiased normalised autocorrelation function?

Tags: correlation, autocorrelation, unbiased-estimator, signal-processing

I am trying to calculate the unbiased normalised autocorrelation function. I think this field is a little complicated as different sources appear to use different nomenclature to describe the same thing, and the same nomenclature to describe different things, so I will try to be specific in what I mean.

I want to perform the autocorrelation for a discrete time series $x[n]=(x_1,x_2,x_3...x_N)$ as a function of time-lag $\tau$, where $\tau$ is an integer. The autocorrelation function I would use is
$$\mathrm{AC}[\tau]=\frac{1}{N-\tau}\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{(x[n]-\bar{x})*(x[n+\tau]-\bar{x})}{\sigma_x^2}$$
where $\bar{x}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N x[n]$ and $\sigma_x=\sqrt{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N(x[n]-\bar{x})^2}$ are the mean and standard deviation, respectively$^\mathrm{*}$.

For $\tau=0$ there is no time lag, the signal perfectly overlaps with itself, and the value is normalised to 1. For a lag of $\tau=1$, there is now an element from each side of the signal that no longer overlaps, for $\tau=2$ there are now two elements that don't overlap, etc.

Should I just use the same value of $\bar{x}$ and $\sigma_x$ for all $\tau$, or should I recalculate $\bar{x}$ and $\sigma_x$ to only include the elements that overlap? So in my image below, when $\tau=2$, should I re-calculate the mean and standard deviation using only elements 3-11 and 1-9?

[image: Diagram showing signal overlap in autocorrelation calculation for a signal with 11 elements, and tau = 0, 1, and 2.]

Diagram showing signal overlap in autocorrelation calculation for a signal with 11 elements, and $\tau$ = 0, 1, and 2.

My instinct is no, and use elements 1-11 for all $\tau$, but when I do, I no longer have an autocorrelation function that is bound between -1 and 1, see my specific example below.

[image: Autocorrelation function using the same mean and standard deviation for all tau which is not bound between 1 and -1. Note here, tau in the x-axis is not number of elements, but is instead time. As sampling frequency is 4 MHz, a displacement of 4 elements is 1 us. N=4096 in this example.]

Autocorrelation function using the same mean and standard deviation for all $\tau$ which is not bound between 1 and -1. Note here, $\tau$ in the x-axis is not number of elements, but is instead time. As sampling frequency is 4MHz, a displacement of 4 elements is 1$\mu$s. $N$=4096 in this example.

*I know that if I'm using a sample of the time series rather tha the whole thing I should divide by $N-1$ in the calculation of the standard deviation, but N>>1 in my work, so I leave that out for simplicity's sake).

Comment: You are summing over $N$ terms but dividing by $N - \tau$.  Many people use a single variance term on the bottom on the grounds that separate SDs should be (very) close for a stationary series and autocorrelation is something between awkward and useless if you don't have approximate stationarity.  In statistics in my reading autocorrelation is always unit-free and so a term "normalized" is redundant. The autocovariance function in contrast has units of measurement. Outside statistics proper, autocorrelation seems often defined differently Small biases exist everywhere here.

Comment: SD with divisor $N$ is not an unbiased estimator of SD, although that rarely bites. Also, what is best depends on whether you are following with spectrum calculations.

Comment: What  Nick said is spot on. Just two add two small things: Brian Ripley's yellow text "Modern Applied Statistics with Splus",  I think has the unbiased formula for autocorrelation. It's not intuitive. Also, as far as changing calculations, to account for overlap, I've never heard of such a procedure.

Comment: @NickCox that's an interesting point about the SD being close to unchanging for a stationary signal, the same should be approximately equal for the mean as well, and when it's put that way is a good justification for not changing that.

You're right about the sum to N still in a sense. I still think of it as summing between the same limits but with zero-padding (thinking in terms of implimenting it in the code), although one signal is summed 1 to N-k and the other k to N. I guess in my diagram I should have had the second signal moving to the left instead too.

Comment: @mlofton I have a version of cross-correlation where if I'm looking at selection of signal length $N$ which is a part of a much longer signal with length >> N where as I increase $\tau$ I slide the window over and use new data from the larger signal (from $\tau$ to $N + \tau$), and it got me thinking about changing the mean and standard deviation in the "normal" implimentation of auto/cross-correlation.

Comment: Steven: it sounds like you are trying to use some heuristic to handle the overlap. I understand your concerns and it's brave of you to try to deal with the overlap and non-overlap but  very many people have dealt with the statistical aspects of the autocorrelation function so, if someone came up with an unbiased estimator of the auto-correlations, I would definitely use that. Can you get your hands on the Ripley text ? I think Venables was a co-author. I'll send a link.

Comment: My mistake in that Bill Venables was the lead author. It's an old book but I don't know where else the formula is. I hope that you can find a free version. It was kind of the bible of statistical computing atleast until R got so much traction. https://www.amazon.com/Modern-Applied-Statistics-S-PLUS-Computing/dp/0387988254/ref=sr_1_1?crid=1GPX960YB9SDD&keywords=modern+statistics+with+splus&qid=1706210681&sprefix=modern+statistics+with+splus%2Caps%2C104&sr=8-1

Comment: @mlofton I guess I was just always unsure if the space over which they were measuring the mean/standard deviation moved with the windows or not. I'd never thought they did, until I found my cross-correlation was no longer between -1 and 1. I guess it doesn't matter too much - I'm not interested in the minimum peaks, and unless the signal has zero noise, is perfectly repeating at the right frequency compared to the sampling frequency, and has no decorrelation, then I don't have to worry too much really.

Comment: Hi Steven: I'm not sure what you mean when you the term "space" in the first line. Sure, some lags will have more "observations" than other lags, if you will, but that doesn't play a role in unbiased-ness. Also, the autocorrelation at any lag should be between between -1 and +1 so, if you writing your own code for it, there has to be a bug. Note that cross-correlation and auto-correlaton are fairly different animals so I wouldn't use the terms interchangeably.

Comment: Auto-corrrelation is the correlation of a series with lags of itself. Cross-correlation is the correlation of two different series with each other and it's not symmetric like auto-correlation.

Comment: @mlofton you're right, space is a bad word to use there, I mean elements of the signal I'm performing the correlation on. I thought the only difference between cross-correlation and auto-correlation was that the auto-correlation was a cross-correlation with itself - the operation you perform on the signals is identical isn't it?

Comment: @mlofton interesting about the bug though. I'm using python and numpy. I have my signal which I remove the mean from ```sig```, and I calculate the standard deviation ```std``` of that. Then I use ```np.correlate(sig, sig, mode='full') / (N * std**2)``` where ```N``` is length ```len(sig)*2 - 1``` (same output length of ```np.correlate``` with ```mode=full```) and goes from 1 to ```len(sig)``` and back to 1 in increments of 1 (and -1). Is this not correct for the un-biased auto-correlation?

Comment: Hi Steven: For the first question, you're right that auto-corr is cross-cor with itself. But cross-cor at some lag is not the same as cross-cor at the negative lag whereas auto-corr at some lag is the same as the negative lag.

Comment: So, if you're algorithm is giving you different values at say lag 1 and lag -1, then something is buggy. cross-corr at lag x can give a different value than cross cor at  -x but not in the auto-corr case. Let me look around and see if I can find the venables-ripley book autocorr formula. I can't really follow the formula you wrote but let me look and get back to you.

Comment: Steven: Here is a beautiful derivation by Ben from back in 2018. If you can follow that, that will probably clear things up for you. But I'll keep looking for what the venable-ripley discussion. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/278703/how-to-estimate-the-autocorrelation-function

Comment: Hi Steven: Somehow, I found what I think might be a photo of the book I've been talking about. So, when you look through it, click one page at a time because it's slow moving. But, if you go over the first couple of pages of chapter 14 carefully, you'll see how tricky and subtle is to calculate the auto-corr function correctly. I think, if you're REALLY interested in unbiased-ness, you should look at the details of the auto-corr function in R, assuming it didn't change from S+ and it probably didn't since venables and ripley were both heavily involved in the development of R.

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/224817420_Modern_Applied_Statistics_With_S

Comment: @mlofton Thank you for taking the time to respond and engage me in this conversation. My auto-correlation is indeed symmetric, and my cross-correlation function of ```A,B``` at lag $\tau$ is equal to my cross-correlation of ```B,A``` at $-\tau$, as expected. In that sense, I'm happy.

Comment: The other stackExchange question you link to is interesting. His point about being asymptotically unbiased as $\tau$ increases due to dissipation (be it by decorrelation or movement, etc) definitely applies in my case. As I tend to take pretty large $N$ for what I'm doing (particularly compared with the $N$ over which the signal decorrelates) I think it's ok to stick with the "biased" one. I will take a read of that book you sent too at some point. Unfortunately I have no experience with R, hence why I'm using python. I'm sure someone has ported everything R can do to python though, somewhere.

Comment: Hi Steven. It sounds like you are okay now. If you are REALLY INTERESTED in the unbiased estimate, use the autocorr formula in Venable-Ripley book. Also, the cross-correlation function is NOT symmetric and the autocorrelation function is symmetric which is why I would use the term auto-correlation and not cross- correlation. The reason for the asymmetricity of the cross-correlation function is because crosscorr(x,y) at lag $\tau$ DOES NOT equal  croscorr(y, x) at lag $\tau$ but autocorr($x_t, x_{t-\tau}$) = autocorr($x_{t-\tau}, x_t$).